# Get Output from sqlplus prompt in bash script

Tags: sqlplus

I have an issue in writing a bash script.

I am trying to get output from sqlplus prompt to a bash variable. I tried many ways as suggested in many forums.

```
t=$(./bin/sqlplus 'oracleuser/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=192.168.1.2)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=connectstring)))' << END
SELECT (1 - (Sum(getmisses)/(Sum(gets) + Sum(getmisses)))) * 100 FROM V\$rowcache;
 exit;
END
)

echo $t
```

This is what I am trying to do exactly. In the above, I am generating the string

```
'oracleuser/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=192.168.1.2)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=connectstring)))'
```

dynamically. This part works well, Issue comes when I am passing the command

```
SELECT (1 - (Sum(getmisses)/(Sum(gets) + Sum(getmisses)))) * 100 FROM V\$rowcache;
```

in sqlplus prompt. Here what happens is like, $ symbol is getting escaped, But the * symbol causes issues (like in sqlprompt it lists all files in the directory from which it runs!) when running the command as a whole.

I have coded like this :-

```
connect="'oracleuser/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=192.168.1.2)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=connectstring)))'"

arr[1]="SELECT (1 - (Sum(getmisses)/(Sum(gets) + Sum(getmisses)))) * 100 FROM V\$rowcache;"

exp=$(./bin/sqlplus $mconnect << END
printf "${arr[1]}";
exit;
END
)

echo $exp
```

when running the script, it successfully enters to sqlplus, but when running SELECT command * causing issues, But if I am entering the commands manually it works.

Is there a better way exists ? I am not a bash geek :( .

I need some real help!

Thanks for taking time to look at my issue.

Best regards,
Bhuvanesh

Answer (score 0):

How about running the query as a separate query1.sql file?

Also, if you only want the result (in this case, of (1 - (Sum(getmisses)/(Sum(gets) + Sum(getmisses)))) * 100) returned and no header info, use sqlplus -S.

```
sqlplus -h
```

> -S             Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
>                 the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
>                 commands.

bash.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
    connect="'oracleuser/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=192.168.1.2)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=connectstring)))'"

    exp=$(./bin/sqlplus -S $connect << END
    @query1.sql
    END
    )

echo $exp
```

query1.sql:

```
SET HEAD OFF
SELECT count(*) from all_users;
exit
```

Then run the example..

```
./bash.sh
36
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. This approach will work, But I was trying to implement a single script file where the parameters are modified and queries are passed to the sql session. So for queries I will add it as array elemets or values to variables, so that it can be called when I start sqlplus session from the same script.